# Aperture (iPhoto) quick view

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, photos.app, aperture, quicklook

I’ve put all my photographs into Aperture’s photo library which means that in the Finder they are hidden in a special folder, making it virtually impossible to quickly browse the photos there. On the other hand, starting up Aperture quickly demands more than 1 GB of RAM, which is something I’d really like to avoid.

In ‘Open File’ dialogues there is a ‘Media’ option which more or less does what I’m looking for. Is there a way to add this to the Finder (Snow Leopard) or is there some external program, I could use as a quick viewer?

(As the situation is similar to iPhoto, I’d expect solutions for the iPhoto library to work as well.)

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

1. Make a Media Browser with Automator - takes about 30 seconds - and you can invoke it in many ways - including with a contextual menu its,
2. Install an app like http://www.karelia.com/imedia/ which will do the same with some extra bells and whistles.

That said, if you use an app like Aperture or iPhoto to manage your photos then they are the "go-to" apps for anything to do with your photos - including viewing them. What you have there is an argument for getting more Ram ;)

If you really want to you could run either app in Referenced Mode. This would leave your Masters (and note: Masters only) accessible via the Finder. While I am happy recommending Aperture in Referenced Mode, I would have significant reservations about running iPhoto in that way.

Comment: My MacBook doesn’t allow me to use more than 4 GB. No doubt, I’d install more if it was possible. :)

Comment: Hmm. ‘Ask for photos’ in Automator only shows iPhoto and Photo Booth; iMedia does not give me an album overview when the top level is selected which would make it much more useful.